# Postgres buitin function to escape special character

Tags: sql, postgresql, escaping

I have 2 columns that I want to compare based on Postgres `SIMILAR TO` notation, in the example below it is the `~*`. Lets call the columns: COLUMN1 and COLUMN2.
It works on most of the rows, then after further investigation if the value of either column has "++" the query failed.

```
SELECT
CASE
   WHEN 'gcc' ~* 'gcc++' THEN 1
   ELSE 2
END
```

with the following message

```
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
```

Obviously the gcc++ string above need to be escaped.

**Question:**
Is the there a Postgres built-in function in postgres that escape the column values so that the comparison can be made safer? I'm thinking something like below ...

```
SELECT
CASE
   WHEN escapeMe(COLUMN1) ~* escapeMe(COLUMN2) THEN 1
   ELSE 2
END
FROM TABLE_T1
```

Comment: What is the point in using `similar to` if the second column is not a regular expression?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. If all characters are escaped, you might as well write `lower('gcc') = lower('gcc++')`. By the way, `~*` is not `SIMILAR TO`, but a regular expression match. Can you specify when you want the comparison to yield `TRUE`?